# How to enforce Hibernate to return only one entity instead of bunch?

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my problem. I'm searching a User entity in DB using Hibernate. But my search criteria allows not only one result (users). How to enforce Hibernate to return only single User object instead of bunch?

My code:

```
public User findUser(String name) {
    return (User) getSession().
            createCriteria(User.class).
            add(Restrictions.like("name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)).
            uniqueResult();
}
```

Example of Hibernate exception when matching more than one result:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 5
```

Comment: Change like to equals.. Restrictions.like("name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE) returns more than one record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query returns several users, and not just one. `uniqueResult()` is for queries returning only one user, and it throws an exception to make you realize that the query doesn't actually return a unique result. If you just want the first of the users returns by the query, use

```
Criteria c = getSession().
        createCriteria(User.class).
        add(Restrictions.like("name", name, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
c.setMaxResults(1);
List<User> users = c.list();
return users.isEmpty() ? null : users.get(0);
```

Note that you can't have any guarantee about which of the 5 users will actually be returned. To be more deterministic, you should add an `order by id` clause to the query.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Thanx for answer.

Comment: To add `order by id` something like that `addOrder(Order.asc("id")`?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you try it?